# 401 Forbidden when calling a GET route from React to SailsJs

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am trying to create a new route with SailJS that will make a GET call.

Here is the route:

```
  'GET /operation/:operationId/sums': 'OperationController.getSums',
```

I also add a line in `policies.js`

```
'OperationController': {
    '*': false,
    'create': ['isAuthorized', 'asPermission', 'operationPolicies'], 
    'find': ['isAuthorized', 'asPermission'],
    'getSums': ['isAuthorized'],
  },
```

When I put `'getSums': true,`, it will work

but when I put it `isAuthorized`, it will give me : 401 Forbidden

Here is my isAuthorized method:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  if (sails.config.environment === 'development' || sails.config.environment === 'local') {
    if (sails.config.custom.debug.token === false) {
      sails.log.debug("Token \t\t | Access permission : \t ok");
      return next();
    }
  }
  let token;
  if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization) {
    let parts = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if (parts.length !== 2) {
      return res.status(401).json({err: 'Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]'});
    }
    let scheme = parts[0],
      credentials = parts[1];

    if (/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme)) {
      token = credentials;
    }

  } else if (req.param('token')) {
    token = req.param('token');
    // We delete the token from param to not mess with blueprints
    delete req.query.token;
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({err: 'No Authorization header was found'});
  }

  jwToken.verify(token, async function (err, token) {
    if (err) return res.status(401).json(
      {err: 'Invalid Token!'}
    );
    req.token = token; // This is the decrypted token or the payload you provided
    req.user = await User.find(token.id);
    return next();
  });
};
```

Here I checked my JWT Token is OK, and that I get data inside `req.user`

Also, I am in `local` environment, so it should not even perform the checks.

Also, I have a 401 error code, but none come from this script, it just says `forbidden`

What can I do to fix it ? I don't know where to find the error.

Comment: I don't see the error just by looking at your code. I would add log lines throughout your policy so you can see which code is actually running. One possibility - maybe the callback of `jwToken.verify` isn't being invoked, leaving your policy with no `next()` or other response handling.